# wxWidgets cursor over panel border

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've got a variety of wxPanels contained in a main wxPanel which is in turn contained in a wxFrame.
I'm trying to set a custom cursor over all the children by calling SetCursor on the wxFrame that contains everything and it mostly works except when the mouse is over the children's border.
When the mouse is over a border, it reverts to the arrow.
Each border is set to wxBORDER_RAISED.

How do I make sure that my cursor is the same over a panel's borders as it is over the panel itself?

Here's how I set the cursor:
In my wxFrame

```
wxCursor wMyCursor(wCursorFilename, wxBITMAP_TYPE_CUR);
SetCursor(wMyCursor);
//tried this as well
wMainPanel->SetCursor(wMyCursor);
```

An other way of putting it might be "how do I set a custom cursor when the mouse is over a panel's border"?

cheers

Comment: If you post the code on how you decide to change the mouse cursor we might be able to help you.

Comment: point taken. however, I just set the cursor in the main frame and never change it afterward.